# Swift 4: How to update image Property?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

Can someone help me fix the code below so that the image data property is updated properly and getImage() is not returning nil? Also, after the image is downloaded, the image data property of the Photo object should be updated and save the context. I am using SimSim to view the content of the database. After loading the photo album, the image data column is showing NULL values. 
Thank you in advance!!

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionPhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionCell
    let photo = photos[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    if let getImage = photo.getImage() {
        cell.photoImageView.image = getImage
    } else {
        // Photo Placeholder
        cell.photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "imgPlaceholder.png")

        // Activity Indicator
        cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        FlickrClient().imageData(photo) {
            (imageData, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                cell.photoImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            }
        }
    }    
    cell.photoImageView.alpha = 1.0
    return cell
}
```

Comment: you can use SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: what is `FlickrClient`? also, you claim that "Also, after the image is downloaded, the image data property of the Photo object should be updated and save the context" - should be? you did not show the code for this - couldn't that be the source of the problem?

Comment: is your getImage method Asynchronous ?

Comment: One issue you could run into is cell reuse.  You dequeue a cell for a specific index path and start the FlickrClient request for the image.  However by the time that returns with the image the user has scrolled on in the list and the cell has been reused for a different index path.  So what you end up doing is putting the incorrect image in the cell.  This can eventually sort itself out but also go wrong if the images arrive in a different order to you requesting them.

Comment: I will look into SDwebImage. Thanks.

Comment: FlickrClient is where I have the HTTP methods, requests, etc. I'm downloading photos from Flickr, and they are populated in a collectionView. The problem is if I clear the cache, the app will have to re-download them again and that's what I'm trying to avoid. I do have a Sqlite, where I should be storing the downloaded images in, can anyone help with that? 

getImage method is not Asynchronous

Comment: I think cell reuse won't be an issue if I store the images in the database.